# Generic LINQ query predicate?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq, lambda

Not sure if this is possible or if I'm expressing correctly what I'm looking for, but I have the following piece of code in my library repeatedly and would like to practice some DRY. 
I have set of SQL Server tables that I'm querying based on a simple user-supplied search field ala Google. I'm using LINQ to compose the final query based on what's in the search string. I'm looking for a way to use generics and passed in lambda functions to create a reusable routine out of this:

```
string[] arrayOfQueryTerms = getsTheArray();

var somequery = from q in dataContext.MyTable
                select q;

if (arrayOfQueryTerms.Length == 1)
{
    somequery = somequery.Where<MyTableEntity>(
        e => e.FieldName.StartsWith(arrayOfQueryTerms[0]));
}
else
{
    foreach(string queryTerm in arrayOfQueryTerms)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(queryTerm))
        {
            somequery = somequery 
                        .Where<MyTableEntity>(
                            e => e.FieldName.Contains(queryTerm));
        }
    }
}
```

I was hoping to create a generic method with signature that looks something like:

```
private IQueryable<T> getQuery(
    T MyTableEntity, string[] arrayOfQueryTerms, Func<T, bool> predicate)
```

I'm using the same search strategy across all my tables, so the only thing that really differs from usage to usage is the MyTable & MyTableEntity searched and the FieldName searched. Does this make sense? Is there a way with LINQ to dynamically pass in the name of the field to query in the where clause? Or can I pass in this as a predicate lambda?

```
e => e.FieldName.Contains(queryTerm)
```

I realize there a million and a half ways to do this in SQL, probably easier, but I'd love to keep everything in the LINQ family for this one. Also, I feel that generics should be handy for a problem like this. Any ideas?

Comment: Same question but for Select clause: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376947/how-can-i-construct-and-save-to-a-db-for-later-use-a-semi-arbitrary-lambda-expre

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for Dynamic Linq. Take a look [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx). This allows you to pass strings as arguments to the query methods, like:

```
var query = dataSource.Where("CategoryID == 2 && UnitPrice > 3")
                      .OrderBy("SupplierID");
```

Edit: Another set of posts on this subject, using C# 4's Dynamic support: [Part 1](http://weblogs.asp.net/davidfowler/archive/2010/08/04/dynamic-linq-a-little-more-dynamic.aspx) and [Part 2](http://weblogs.asp.net/davidfowler/archive/2010/08/19/dynamic-linq-part-2-evolution.aspx).

Comment: Thanks! Very cool, I need to look through all of ScottGu's blog posts on this topic...

Comment: Unfortunately I've only found the one - I thought he had a series but I guess I was wrong. There are other sources of information though.

Comment: sorry to ask one question here. what is predicate and how it is related to linq?

Comment: A predicate is an expression that evaluates to a bool. Predicates are used as arguments to Where clauses in LINQ expressions. In the example above, ``CategoryID == 2 && UnitPrice > 3`` is a predicate.

Comment: I think Gridify is a better alternative. https://github.com/alirezanet/Gridify

Comment: @AliReza I'll check it out. =)

Answer (score 7):

What it sounds like is you want basically a conditional predicate builder..

I hope you can mold this into something you are looking for, good luck!

http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Answer (score 6):

You might want to look at expression trees:

```
IQueryable<T> getQuery<T>(T myTableEntity, string[] arrayOfQueryTerms, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
 { var fieldOrProperty = getMemberInfo(predicate);
   /* ... */
 }

MemberInfo getmemberInfo<T>(Expression<Func<T,bool> expr)
 { var memberExpr = expr as MemberExpression;
   if (memberExpr != null) return memberExpr.Member;
   throw new ArgumentException();
 }

var q = getQuery<FooTable>(foo, new[]{"Bar","Baz"}, x=>x.FieldName);
```

Comment: I think the Dynamic LINQ answer is what I'm going to go with, but thanks for this, I will also try and work through this tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest trying the **[Gridify](https://github.com/alirezanet/Gridify)** library.
It is much easier to work with also it has better performance.

usage example:

```cs
query = dataSource.ApplyFiltering("FiledName=John");
```

this is a performance comparison between dynamic LINQ libraries.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to do this same thing. You will need [Dynamic Linq](http://talesfromthebleedingedge.blogspot.com/2008/10/linq-to-entities-dynamic-linq-to.html) [here](http://talesfromthebleedingedge.blogspot.com/2008/10/linq-to-entities-dynamic-linq-to.html) is a way to keep this strongly typed.