# Dynamic LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq, dynamic

I have an XML document defined like so

**XML File**

```
<TABLE>
    <RECORD>
        <PAGENUMBER> 1 Of 1</PAGENUMBER>
        <OtherFields1>..</OtherFields1>
        <OtherFields2>..</OtherFields2>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
        <PAGENUMBER> 1 Of 2</PAGENUMBER>
        <OtherFields1>..</OtherFields1>
        <OtherFields2>..</OtherFields2>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
        <PAGENUMBER> 2 Of 2</PAGENUMBER>
        <OtherFields1>..</OtherFields1>
        <OtherFields2>..</OtherFields2>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
        <PAGENUMBER> 1 Of 1</PAGENUMBER>
        <OtherFields1>..</OtherFields1>
        <OtherFields2>..</OtherFields2>
    </RECORD>
</TABLE>
```

I'm trying to create a dynamic query where i can put a "Fieldname", "Operand", "Value"
in a config and LINQ can build a predicate based on it.

**Config File**

```
<CLAUSES>
    <CLAUSE name="PAGENUMBER" operand="!=">Page 1 Of 1</CLAUSE>
    <CLAUSE name="OtherFields1" operand="!=">String.Empty</CLAUSE>
</CLAUSES>
```

Here is the LINQ i'm using now

**LINQ Query**

```
        XDocument jobXML = XDocument.Load(JobFile);

        List<ClauseObj> clauses = new List<ClauseObj>();
        clauses.Add(new ClauseObj { Field = "PAGENUMBER", Operand = "!=", Value = " Page 1 Of 1" });

        var q = jobXML.Descendants("RECORD").AsEnumerable();

        foreach (var c in clauses)
        {
            switch (c.Operand)
            {
                case "!=":
                    q = q.Where(r => r.Element(c.Field).Value != c.Value);
                    break;
            }
        }
```

how can i make it read the where clauses "dynamically"
and also specify which field names to return?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125400/generic-linq-query-predicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string clause = "PAGENUMBER";
string operand = "!=";
string value= " Page 1 Of 1";

  var q = from r in jobXML.Descendants("RECORD")
                 select new
                 {
                     PAGENUMBER = (string)r.Element("PAGENUMBER"),
                     OtherFields1 = (string)r.Element("OtherFields1")
                 }

   switch(operand)
   {
       case "!=":
          q = q.Where(r=> r.Element(clause).Value != value);
          break;
       case "etc":
   }

   var list = q.ToList();
```

Comment: that's close; but what about the select area being dynamic ?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Dynamic Linq Queries Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397982.aspx). They have a class in there that adds various extensions methods for Where and Order By

Comment: I've already looked at it it, and I've attempted to use it to avail.
Maybe an example in my use case would be more helpful ?

Comment: Ohn you need the select dynamic as well hmm...no idea...but you should be able to use it to get rid of your switch.