# Genericising one class to handle multiple types

Tags: c#

I have a series of about 30 lookup tables in my database schema, all with the same layout (and I would prefer to keep them as separate tables rather than one lookup table), and thus my Linq2SQL context has 30 entities for these lookup tables.

I have a standard class that I would use for CRUD operations on each of these 30 entites, for example:

```
public class ExampleAttributes : IAttributeList
{
    #region IAttributeList Members

    public bool AddItem(string Item, int SortOrder)
    {
        MyDataContext context = ContextHelper.GetContext();
        ExampleAttribute a = new ExampleAttribute();
        a.Name = Item;
        a.SortOrder = SortOrder;
        context.ExampleAttributes.InsertOnSubmit(a);

        try
        {
            context.SubmitChanges();
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public bool DeleteItem(int Id)
    {
        MyDataContext context = ContextHelper.GetContext();

        ExampleAttribute a = (from m in context.ExampleAttributes
                            where m.Id == Id
                            select m).FirstOrDefault();

        if (a == null)
            return true;

        // Make sure nothing is using it
        int Count = (from m in context.Businesses
                             where m.ExampleAttributeId == a.Id
                             select m).Count();

        if (Count > 0)
            return false;

        // Delete the item
        context.ExampleAttributes.DeleteOnSubmit(a);

        try
        {
            context.SubmitChanges();
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public bool UpdateItem(int Id, string Item, int SortOrder)
    {
        MyDataContext context = ContextHelper.GetContext();

        ExampleAttribute a = (from m in context.ExampleAttributes
                            where m.Id == Id
                            select m).FirstOrDefault();

        a.Name = Item;
        a.SortOrder = SortOrder;

        try
        {
            context.SubmitChanges();
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public String GetItem(int Id)
    {
        MyDataContext context = ContextHelper.GetContext();
        var Attribute = (from a in context.ExampleAttributes
                         where a.Id == Id
                         select a).FirstOrDefault();

        return Attribute.Name;
    }

    public Dictionary<int, string> GetItems()
    {
        Dictionary<int, string> Attributes = new Dictionary<int, string>();

        MyDataContext context = ContextHelper.GetContext();
        context.ObjectTrackingEnabled = false;

        Attributes = (from o in context.ExampleAttributes orderby o.Name select new { o.Id, o.Name }).AsEnumerable().ToDictionary(k => k.Id, v => v.Name);

        return Attributes;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

I could replicate this class 30 times with very minor changes for each lookup entity, but that seems messy somehow - so can this class be genericised so I can also pass it the type I want, and have it handle internally the type differences in the linq queries?  That way, I have one class to make additions to, one class to bug fix et al - seems the way that it should be done.

**UPDATE:**

Andrews answer below gave me the option that I was really looking at while thinking about the question (passing the type in) but I need more clarification on how to genericise the linq queries.  Can anyone clarify this?

Cheers

Moo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple things you can try.

One is to define an interface that has all the relevant fields that the thirty entity classes share.  Then, you would be able to have each entity class implement this interface (let's call it `IMyEntity`) by doing something like

```
public partial class EntityNumber1 : IMyEntity
{
}
```

for each entity (where `EntityNumber1` is the name of one of the entity classes).  Granted, this is still thirty different definitions, but your CRUD operation class could then operate on `IMyEntity` instead of having to write a new class each time.

A second way to do this is simply to genericize the CRUD operation class, as you suggest:

```
public class ExampleAttributes<T> : IAttributeList
{
    ...
```

which allows you to use T as the type on which to operate.  Granted, this might be easier in combination with the first method, since you would still have to check for the presence of the attributes and cast the entity to the appropriate type or interface.

**Edit:**

To check for the presence of the appropriate properties on the entity, you might need to use reflection methods.  One way to check whether the given type T has a particular property might be to check for

```
typeof(T).GetProperties().OfType<PropertyInfo>().Count<PropertyInfo>(pi => pi.Name == "MyPropertyName" && pi.GetGetMethod().ReturnType == typeof(TypeIWant)) > 0
```

Of course, replace `TypeIWant` with the type you are expecting the property to be, and replace `MyPropertyName` with the name of the property for which you are checking.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you go further into depth on the second option at all?

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for the extra detail, unfortunately its the genericising of the linq based on the given type that I really need clarification on - I will update the question to that effect but thankyou for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Add a parameter to the constructors which specifies the type.  Then you can work with it internally.  One class, with perhaps a switch statement in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

For genericising a LINQ query, the biggest problem is that your DataContext has the collections based on type.  There are a few ways this can be circumvented.  You could try to access it using reflection, but that will require quite a bit of hacking and would pretty much destroy all efficiency that LINQ to SQL would provide.

The easiest way seems to be to use Dynamic LINQ.  I have not used it personally, but it seems like it should support it.  You can find more information in this thread: [Generic LINQ query predicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125400/generic-linq-query-predicate)
and on http://aspalliance.com/1569_Dynamic_LINQ_Part_1_Using_the_LINQ_Dynamic_Query_Library.1
Maybe someone else can provide more information about this?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't necessarily an answer to the question, but may be a solution to your problem. Have you considered generating all the classes that you need? T4 is built into Visual Studio, and can generate code for you. The link below describes it fairly broadly, but contains heaps of links for further information.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/T4TextTemplateTransformationToolkitCodeGenerationBestKeptVisualStudioSecret.aspx

That way, you can define all the methods in one place, and generate the class files for your 30-odd lookup models. One place to make changes etc.

Maybe worth considering, and if not, still worth knowing about.