# Query Object Structure using string input

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic

I'm trying to find a clean way to allow input of a string that can then query an object structure. I think a dynamic linq query is what I want but I can't figure out how to implement this.

The user would input a string like

relationship.IsHappy = true
or 
relationship.Type = "Uncle"
or 
relationship.Type = "Uncle" && relationship.IsHappy = true

The last two lines in main() are what I'm trying to find a solution for:

```
string zQuery = args[0];
me.Realtionships.Where(zQuery);
```

Complete code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Linq.Dynamic;

namespace LinqTest1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            person me = new person();
            me.FirstName = "Andy";
            me.Realtionships = new List<relationship>();

            person aunt = new person();
            aunt.FirstName = "Lucy";

            relationship rAunt = new relationship();
            rAunt.IsHappy = true;
            rAunt.Type = "Aunt";
            rAunt.Person = aunt;
            me.Realtionships.Add(rAunt);

            person uncle = new person();
            uncle.FirstName = "Bob";

            relationship rUncle = new relationship();
            rUncle.IsHappy = false;
            rUncle.Type = "Aunt";
            rUncle.Person = uncle;
            me.Realtionships.Add(rUncle);

            string zQuery = args[0];
            me.Realtionships.Where(zQuery); 

        }
    }


    public class person
    {

        private string _firstName;
        public string FirstName
        {
            get { return _firstName; }
            set { _firstName = value; }
        }

        private string _lastName;
        public string LastName
        {
            get { return _lastName; }
            set { _lastName = value; }
        }

        private List<relationship> _realtionships;
        public List<relationship> Realtionships 
        {
            get { return _realtionships; }
            set { _realtionships = value; }
        }

    }

    public class relationship 
    {
        private string _type;
        public string Type
        {
            get { return _type; }
            set { _type = value; }
        }

        private bool _isHappy;
        public bool IsHappy
        {
            get { return _isHappy; }
            set { _isHappy = value; }
        }

        private person _person;
        public person Person
        {
            get { return _person; }
            set { _person = value; }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: See if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125400/generic-linq-query-predicate

Answer (score 0):

you can use :

- [Dynamic expression trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) Inbuilt libraries

or

- [Dynamic Linq queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/vstudio/bb894665.aspx)  A microsoft library with source and examples you can download.

Constructing an expression tree is a little more involved but ultimately more powerful. And you will eat and sleep Lambda when your have finished.
The Dynamic Linq library allows you to pass strings to a tool that parses the strings and creates Lambda expressions. This is easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

There is a library called dynamic Linq: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx that allows you to use Strings instead of expression trees for Linq queries.

Answer (score 0):

We did this with an expression tree serializer/deserializer. I believe in your case you just need to deserialize the passed in string, we used this http://expressiontree.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. The piece I was missing was AsQueryable(). See solution below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Linq.Dynamic;

namespace LinqTest1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            person me = new person();
            me.FirstName = "Andy";
            me.Realtionships = new List<relationship>();

            person aunt = new person();
            aunt.FirstName = "Lucy";

            relationship rAunt = new relationship();
            rAunt.IsHappy = true;
            rAunt.Type = "Aunt";
            rAunt.Person = aunt;
            me.Realtionships.Add(rAunt);

            person uncle = new person();
            uncle.FirstName = "Bob";

            relationship rUncle = new relationship();
            rUncle.IsHappy = false;
            rUncle.Type = "Uncle";
            rUncle.Person = uncle;
            me.Realtionships.Add(rUncle);

            //string zQuery = args[0];

            var res = me.Realtionships.AsQueryable().Where("Type == \"Uncle\"");
            foreach (relationship item in res)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Person.FirstName); 
            }

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }


    public class person
    {

        private string _firstName;
        public string FirstName
        {
            get { return _firstName; }
            set { _firstName = value; }
        }

        private string _lastName;
        public string LastName
        {
            get { return _lastName; }
            set { _lastName = value; }
        }

        private List<relationship> _realtionships;
        public List<relationship> Realtionships 
        {
            get { return _realtionships; }
            set { _realtionships = value; }
        }

    }

    public class relationship : IEnumerable<relationship> 
    {
        private string _type;
        public string Type
        {
            get { return _type; }
            set { _type = value; }
        }

        private bool _isHappy;
        public bool IsHappy
        {
            get { return _isHappy; }
            set { _isHappy = value; }
        }

        private person _person;
        public person Person
        {
            get { return _person; }
            set { _person = value; }
        }

        public IEnumerator<relationship> GetEnumerator()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Note that "Type == \"Uncle\"" could be the input arg.